# google speech api error 400 : Invalid FLAC header: incorrect FLAC marker

Tags: raspberry-pi, flac, google-speech-api

I'd like to use my own flac file, gs://sttrecording/1111.flac, and flac file itself works perfectly fine, and file directory is correct.
but I keep getting `error 400 Invalid FLAC header: incorrect FLAC marker`....

I changed this : (https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/getting-started)

```
{
  'config': {
      'encoding':'FLAC',
      'sampleRate': 16000,
      'languageCode': 'en-US'
  },
  'audio': {
      'uri':'gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac'
  } 
}
```

to this :

```
{
  'config': {
      'encoding':'FLAC',
      'sampleRate': 16000,
      'languageCode': 'ko-KR'
  },
  'audio': {
      'uri':'gs://sttrecording/1111.flac'
  } 
}
```

any idea why this is happening? 
I'm using RPi3, jessie by the way

Comment: Are you sure it's a flac file and it's 16kHz?  Try running `file 1111.flac` to check the file format.